# Probability of specific sequence of randomly choosen values in a table

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I have a three by three table like this

[ ] [ ] [ ]

[ ] [ ] [ ]

[ ] [ ] [ ]

Each of the tiles can be one of the values: A,B,C.

Each tile gets randomly assigned a value. Each value has the same probability of 1/3.
What is the probability of **only** the top row having the same values.

For example this combination:

[A] [A] [A]

[A] [B] [C]

[B] [B] [A]

would be valid because only the top row has the same values.
How would I go about solving something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would be
$$\frac{3(3^3-3)(3^3-3)}{3^9} \approx 0.0877\ldots$$

This is found by considering that there are three choices for the value in the first row, and by a compliment argument, there are $3^3-3$ choices for the second row (since anything but all the same value works), and similarly for the last row.

Comment: I would have said the probability a particular row has the same values if $\frac19$ and since you want this to happen for the top row and to not happen for both the other two rows, the probability is $\frac19 \times \frac89 \times \frac89$, the same as  your answer

Comment: Oh yes that might be simpler.